# Jupyter Notebook error loading an .ipynb file

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

```
Unreadable Notebook: /home/gerbil/ws_sim/src/rosie_simulation/analysis/get_stats-multi.ipynb NotJSONError('Notebook does not appear to be JSON: u\'{\\n "cells": [\\n {\\n "cell_type": "...',)
```

I get this error when trying to load a .ipynb file that I open using the command jupyter notebook get_stats-multi.ipynb.

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "### Welcome to the metrics document! Please press \"Shift+Enter\" in the cell below to get started! *Please note that any output that is truncated can be fully expanded by clicking on the whitespace to the left of it's respective cell, underneath the ln [#]!"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {
    "scrolled": true
   },
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "%matplotlib inline\n",
    "from rosie_analytics_functions import *"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "# Data Preparation"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "### If you'd like to see all of your available logs, press \"Shift+Enter\" on the cell below "
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {
   "scrolled": true
   },
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
   "!ls ./logs/raw"
   ]
   },
   {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
   "### Please enter the name of the folder where the bags to be processed are located as well as the name of the room it was running in from among (\"IEC\", \"IEC_Multi_Room\", \"IHOS_Section\", or \"IHOS_Section_3_room")"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {
   "scrolled": true
   },
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
   "folder_name" = "\"test\" # Leaving this blank processes all files in logs/raw\n",
   "room_name" = "IEC"
   ]
  },
   {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
   "### Please press \"Shift+Enter\" below to generate result data and CSV files (found in analysis/logs/processed)"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {
   "scrolled": true
   },
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
   "process_all_bags_in_folder(folder_name, room_name)"
   ]
  },
   {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
   "###    "
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
  "display_name": "Python 2",
  "language": "python",
  "name": "python2"
  },
  "language_info": {
  "codemirror_mode": {
  "name": "ipython",
  "version": 2
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython2",
   "version": "2.7.12"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

Here is the file that I'm trying to load. As far as I can tell it meets JSON's syntax for files, but I have very little experience with JSON and I could be missing something small...

Comment: There are  a  couple of errors with the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with

```
"### Please ... ... ... or \"IHOS_Section_3_room")"
```

And ending with:

```
   "folder_name" = "\"test\"
```

There are mismatched quotation marks, leading to an uninterpretable JSON. Barring other mistakes, fixing this should have the Notebook be a happy camper.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy code from the browser, and you have JSON parser/viewer extension installed, this extension could cause the problem. Disable JSON viewer then copy the code and try again.